# Installing PHP 5.6 on El Capitan: Syntax error with httpd.conf

Tags: php, apache, osx-elcapitan

While I am using MAMP Pro, I need to install Elasticsearch via OS X itself. However, I also need PHP 5.6 and El Capitan comes with 5.5 (I'm using OS X 10.11.6).

I followed a [set of PHP installation instructions](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/upgrade-php-on-osx/) which resulted in an error:

> httpd: Syntax error on line 119 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:
>   Cannot load modules/mod_unixd.so into server:
>   dlopen(/usr/modules/mod_unixd.so, 10): image not found

I did a bit of Googling, but failed to find anything definitive, and I'd prefer not to go making changes to `httpd.conf` until I have clue one.

I'm using Apache...

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Unix)
Server built:   Feb 20 2016 20:03:19
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:52
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.8, APR-UTIL 1.5.2
Compiled using: APR 1.4.8, APR-UTIL 1.5.2
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
```

Line 119 is:

> LoadModule unixd_module modules/mod_unixd.so

Comment: Whats `on line 119 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` ? Can you post some config to make this question easier to answer?

Comment: @spacepickle, I'm not too familiar with the command line, so apologies. I've added a bit more information to the question.

Comment: DId the php installation script change something in your httpd configuration? What happens if you commment out line 119?

Comment: @spacepickle, I commented it out, ran `sudo apachectl start` which went ahead with no errors. However, when I then ran `php -v` it reads: PHP 5.5.36 (cli) (built: May 29 2016 01:07:06). So the installation appears to have failed.

Comment: Are you able to get a php page to render? what does phpinfo() tell you about the install?It could be that the command line php is still 5.5 and apache is using something else

Comment: When I visit either http://127.0.0.1/ or http://localhost, I get: "This site can’t be reached 127.0.0.1 refused to connect." So while Apache _appears_ to be running, there's something wrong.

Comment: @spacepickle, would it make sense to remove (uninstall) PHP and start again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142336/discussion-between-spacepickle-and-wayne-smallman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP installer had messed with the base httpd.conf file (commented out a ton of stuff) and added a new `+php-osx.conf` file in `/etc/apache2/other/`.

The original config for httpd.conf seems to be backed up by default and kept at `/etc/apache2/original/httpd.conf`

Moved the original httpd.conf to a backup location and rename the +php-osx.conf file so it isnt loaded:

```
sudo mv /etc/apache2/httpd.conf /etc/apache2/httpd.conf.original
sudo mv "/etc/apache2/other/+php-osx.conf" "/etc/apache2/+php-osx.conf.bak"
```

Then **copy** the file from the folder `/etc/apache2/original` in as the default conf file:

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/original/httpd.conf /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

This allowed `sudo apachectl start` to work and the webserver to be accessible.

However php is still on 5.5 since the `+php-osx.conf` file has been disabled. To move forward here, the executable defined in that file needs to be used and the other `php5.conf` file disabled. But i currently think that this will not be enough to get php5.6 running